# How can I tell what command an alias stands for?

Tags: bash, alias

`ll` is a common alias in many Linux distros.
How can I tell what it aliases to?

I've tried checking my `.bashrc`, but I am not able tell what `ll` is equivalent to.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the `alias` command.

```
$ alias ll
ll='ls --color=auto -Flh'
```

Answer (score 11):

You can find a list of aliases on the system with the following command

```
type -a ll
```

ll is aliased to `ls -alF'

As a side note, you can see a list of all aliases on the system with

```
compgen -a
```

Comment: you can also type `which ll` to find out

Comment: Also, if you're sure it's an alias, `alias ll` will tell you.

Comment: which ll returns nothing on my ubuntu machine. alias ll does show what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: @EvanTeitelman Please make that an answer. I just wanted to but that would feel strange with you having said just that as a comment.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Thanks, I have posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Typing in the command also lists all the aliases in the shell

```
alias
```

Answer (score 2):

From the manual page for `command`:

> If either the '-V' or '-v' option is supplied, a description of command is printed.

So, `command -v ll` might produce this output: `alias ll='ls -l'`.

Comment: One might go so far as to say " a description or the location of the command is printed" as evidenced by `command -v dd` which produces `/bin/dd`